# Vehicle shifts into neutral; requires restart to get going

Tags: automatic-transmission, buick

2010 Buick Lucerne CXL - My car keeps shifting into neutral every time I come to a stop and I have to turn the car off and back on to get it to go back into drive and I have to do this over and over again and it doesn't go very fast at all if I can get it to stay and drive longer than 30 seconds. What does this mean??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the fluid level checked?

Comment: Presumably the selector stick is still in the drive position when this happens? Will it restart in drive or do you have go back into park/neutral, start the engine then reselect drive?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  When you say "keeps shifting into neutral" does that means the transmission disengages by itself or does it mean that the shift selector moves from D to N on its own?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen from a bad motor mount or mounts. The excessive movement actually moved the gear selector switch on the transmission but didn't effect the display on the dash. In my case it was an older Ford Taurus. It was most likely to occur when slowing down then speeding back up without coming to a complete stop.

Answer (score 0):

Motor mounts may be something to look into, but also check out the neutral safety switch. Because if you are moving the car should not go into neutral by itself. Also see if the brake switch under the brake is making good contact. Hope this helps, good fixn...